# Application is not working under raw system

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, py2exe

I've an python GUI application, I use pyQt4.
I build binary with bbfreeze (before I was using py2exe but it didn't work with email module well).

On system where I build this app, everything works properly, but when I install it on raw windows (without all those vc_redist and set of python libraries) binary does not work.

Where should I start to find a solution, since I have no messages/exceptions/crashes, it simply ends immediately after i run it from command line.

I predict that if I'd install some of tools from "build system" I would run it.
Is this the only way?
I mean, if I would find the missing lib (if it's a lib problem), would adding this library to bbfreeze script would solve this problem?

cheers
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), and run depends.exe on your executable.  It will examine the full tree of DLL dependencies, and mark with a red error the ones that are missing.

It will likely be a MSCVRTxx.dll.